# jQuery custom date function not working properly?

Tags: jquery, date

I have create this jQuery that return me date in format: YYYY-MM-DD

This is my code:

```
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDate();
day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
var year = d.getFullYear();
var date = (year+"-"+month+"-"+day);
```

**Problem is in variable "day"**: It supose to return me day number, for example if day in month is "9", it should return me 09 (2015-01-09); if day in month is "12", it should return me 12 (2015-01-12). But my code returns me in example of "12" day: 2015-01-012 - it puts zero, but it shoudl not, I have no idea why puts this zero...

here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b6afckx5/

Realy thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var day = d.getDate();
day = (day >= 10)? day : '0' + day;
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6afckx5/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

`day` is a number, not a string, it doesn't have a `length` property, so `day.length` is undefined. You need to convert it to a string first:

```
var day = d.getDate().toString();
```

Similarly for the month:

```
var month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

day is Number it doest not have the length property.
You should check if it is less than 10 to prepend the 0.

```
day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day
```

Answer (score 1):

length doesn't accept. your code can be like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDate();
day = day >9 ? day: '0' + day  ;
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
var year = d.getFullYear();
var date = (year+"-"+month+"-"+day);    

$(function(){       
    $('#date').append(date);
});
```